# Unable to insert a newline or carriage return in xml document

Tags: xml, post, curl, newline

I am using curl to perform a PUT request as follows:

```
curl --user admin:pass -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<user>
<disabled>false</disabled>
<local>true</local>
<publicKey>publickeywithnewlines</publicKey>
<userType>STANDARD</userType>
<username>testuser1212</username>
<password>pass</password>
</user>' 
-X POST http://www.dummyaddress.com/api/members/
```

I need to insert both new line and carriage returns at the end of the text contained within the publickey tag. I have tried using tag 
 new line characters such as 
 but nothing seems to work. I have read about -data-binary but don't know how to apply it here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried putting the content into a file like: 
    
    
    false
    true
    Tootsie roll tiramisu macaroon wafer carrot cake\n\n\n\n
    STANDARD
    simpleUser77786
    pass
     
but the curl command doesnt seem to be exiting properly. It's as if the command hasn't finished executing.

It's curl --user admin:pass -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' --data-binary '@template.xml' -X POST http://www.dummyaddress.com/api/users/

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I've just tried, maybe it can help you find out what's going on.

Put your POST data in a file (say `post.xml`), and edit it accodringly.  I've just copy/pasted your initial example here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<user>
<disabled>false</disabled>
<local>true</local>
<publicKey>publickeywithnewlines</publicKey>
<userType>STANDARD</userType>
<username>testuser1212</username>
<password>pass</password>
</user>
```

For debugging, set up a dummy TCP server with `nc`, and pipe the output through `hexdump` so that you can see exactly what gets uploaded to the server:

```
nc -nl -p 8888 | hexdump -C
```

Then run:

```
curl --user admin:pass -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
     --data-binary '@post.xml' -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8888
```

(the leading `@` instructs curl to read the POST data from `test.xml`, making it easier to edit/tune).

With `--data-binary`, your data should be uploaded unaltered.  Of course it's up to you to format your file properly (especially regarding end of line characters).  Here's an excerpt of what I get when I put a couple of CR+LF inside the `<publicKey>` element:

```
...
00000110  75 65 3c 2f 6c 6f 63 61  6c 3e 0a 20 20 3c 70 75  |ue</local>.  <pu|
00000120  62 6c 69 63 4b 65 79 3e  0d 0a 0d 0a 3c 2f 70 75  |blicKey>....</pu|
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
00000130  62 6c 69 63 4b 65 79 3e  0a 20 20 3c 75 73 65 72  |blicKey>.  <user|
...
```

(note the double `0d 0a 0d 0a` at offset `00000128`)

Edit `post.xml` to your exact requirements, then just change the destination URL on the `curl` command line when you're satisfied with the result.

**note**: you should also replace your raw CRs and LFs with proper XML entities: `&#x0d;` and `&#x0a;` respectively.

Comment: I'll try that thanks. For my own reference what did you use to create the CR + LF's in the file? So I know what has worked for you.

Comment: The hexdump in my post was produced with raw LFs (`^v^m` with vi).

Comment: unfortunately that hasn't worked. My key is sent to a rest endpoint that checks its validity (no trailing new lines or carriage returns) but it isn't registering them with this.

Comment: Perhaps they're using other validation methods as well (cookies, etc...).  Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: One last thing I get an access denied error when trying to execute the command to nc how did you determine the address

Comment: I just randomly picked a free TCP port (> 1024, and not appearing in `netstat -lpnt`).